# Missing mingwm10.dll

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am coding a c++ project with Qt Creator. Everything is working fine (debug, release), but when I run the compiled .exe directly (go to exe file and run it) it says mingwm10.dll is missing.

What can I do about this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what you could do:

- as **chalup** said, place you MINGW bin directory to you local/global `PATH` variable like that: My Computer|System Properties|Advenced|Environment Variables|System variables - select `PATH` string and press **Edit** button. After dialog appeared, add something like that - C:\MinGW\bin
- Build you app without mingw, for example with [Qt libraries 4.6.3 for Windows (VS 2008, 194 MB)](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2008)
- Just place `mingwm10.dll` into the directory with your executable file

Comment: If we use that exe file in different system without installing qt,first time it ask mingw10.dll.if we copy it to the directory,it will ask other dll files.If we copy all depended dll files it shows error message.Then how to fix this error without installing qt andmingw?otherwise our program will depended to mingw.

Comment: @KIRAN You could build static EXE (with Qt and mingw libs inside) (this will increase the base size of the EXE, but no more DLLs will be needed any more), or you could build static EXE (static Qt without mingw support - that means when you build static Qt library with `configure` & `make` methods, but you have to set flag `configure -no-exceptions ...` - I'm not really sure - better to check this)

Comment: @KIRAN No, I'm talking about building Qt static lib first ( http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.1/deployment-windows.html ), to be able build static programs. You could turn off mingw dependency with `-no-exceptions` flag while building static Qt. After that only you have to do is to build you project!

Comment: For the ones which use wxWidgets instead of Qt: the DLL is to find under `wxFormBuilder\mingwm10.dll`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the location of mingwm10.dll to your environment PATH variable.

Comment: I don't know the path from the top of my head, but it's somewhere inside the SDK installation, e.g. $QTDIR/mingw/lib. I would search it in explorer and then copy it next to the .exe.
For distributing, put the dll to the shipped Qt dlls.

Comment: Just to be more precise: I found it at `C:\Qt\2010.02.1\qt\bin\mingwm10.dll` on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also build your app statically if you want your application to function as a standalone .exe file.

http://www.formortals.com/how-to-statically-link-qt-4/

Answer (score 1):

If you use Qt as LGPL, you should better accept a few DLLs with your EXE. 
It's not so bad, actually.
Else you are free to compile Qt as a static library or to use Microsoft compilers.
Removing "-mthreads" in all makefiles may help, byt may not, especially if you use exceptions between threads.