# C++: How to ship a single executable without mingwm10.dll

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, static-libraries

I'm creating a small cross platform program with C++/wxWidgets. By using static linking I managed to get only one .exe file for Windows in the end. However it still requires a small (18 KB) mingwm10.dll

Although I can just distribute my app with this dll, I'd prefer to have it "inside" the .exe... Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing mingwm10.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396876/missing-mingwm10-dll)

Comment: yes, I saw that question... so there's no way to do that. that's sad because I could do that with wxPython, the whole Python interpreter was in one single .exe file

Comment: Recompile wxWidgets, QT, or whatever without the dependency ... you probably don't need it.

Comment: Would this work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396876/missing-mingwm10-dll/5665749#5665749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the configure script to compile wxWidgets, add `--disable-threads`. This will set `wxUSE_THREADS` to 0, wxThread class and all the code that depends on threads will not be compiled. Automatically mingwm10.dll will not be linked.

Comment: MinGW has this small library for handling threads because it needs DllMain() to get notified about thread termination. You can't easily get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

The "single EXE that includes all project files" is called a setup script. Consider something like InnoSetup, or MSI.

Rolling your own install DLL on first use code is theoretically possible, but extremely ugly. It gomes like this: you add the DLL (zipped, if possible) to the EXE as resources. On startup, you try to load the DLL; if you cannot, you take it from the resources and place somewhere. And that will break under non-admin user. And the automatic privilege escalation won't work (it works for setup files). And you have to be very careful not to call anything in the DLL before you install it. Like I said, very, very ugly.